# XML: Type definition is absent

Tags: xml, xsd, xmllint

I am using this[1] XML Schema to validate a XML document with xmllint:

```
xmllint --noout --schema mets.xsd metadata.xml
```

The validation fails with

```
metadata.xml:55: element object: Schemas validity error : Element '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}object', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}file' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition. 
metadata.xml:55: element object: Schemas validity error : Element '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}object': The type definition is absent.
```

Line 55 in metadata.xml:

```
<premis:object xsi:type="premis:file" xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2 http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-0.xsd">
```

However, there is an example document for what I want. It is located here[2].

When I validate this example against the schema, the same validation error occurs.

```
louis-2-0.xml:80: element object: Schemas validity error : Element '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}object', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}file' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition.
louis-2-0.xml:80: element object: Schemas validity error : Element '{info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2}object': The type definition is absent.
```

What am I missing?

[1] http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd

[2] http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/louis-2-0.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you refer to as [2] is valid, so the error messages indicate a problem in your local setup.  I'd guess that xmllint is not honoring the schema-location hint you quote from line 55, so it is not fetching the Premis schema and then is not finding the type mentioned.

To test that, try making a simple schema document that imports everthing you want to use, and use it to validate.  Your document uses Mets and Premis, so we'll import those two schemas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
     schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd"
  />

  <xs:import namespace="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2"
    schemaLocation=
      "http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-0.xsd"
  />
</xs:schema>
```

Save this as `mets-premis.xsd` (or any name you like).

Now try validating with `xmllint --noout --schema mets-premis.xsd metatdata.xml`

Comment: That validates the example document louis-2-0.xml, but I get new errors in my document. Your answer pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @c-m-sperberg-mcqueen One follow-up (not worth a new question on SO). I think the namespace declaration in louis-2-0.xml, line 6 is redundant. Right?

Comment: It does seem to duplicate a namespace declaration on the outermost mets:mets element, yes.